# Binding not working because value is undefined

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm following [a KnockoutJS tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/342244/Knockout-that-cascading-dropdown). The list of countries is populated correctly, but on selecting a country, the `country.value` is `undefined`.

The author of the article does state he typed the code in Notepad and it should work, but I'm a KnockoutJS novice so I'm not able to spot the error. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE - 
I replaced the country.value in the following code to use jquery $("#Country").val() and it now works

```
  viewModel.stateSelect = ko.dependentObservable({
        read: viewModel.state,
        write: function (state) {
            this.state(state);
            $.getJSON('http://localhost:56502/KnockoutJS/CascadingDropdown/Cities/' + 
                      country.value, null, function (response) {
                viewModel.cities(response);
            });
        },
        owner: viewModel
    });
```

so the json call looks like this and works too

```
            $.getJSON('http://localhost:56502/KnockoutJS/CascadingDropdown/Cities/' + 
                          $("#Country").val(), null, function (response) {
                              viewModel.states(response);
                          });
```

but it'll be nice to know the error in the KO code as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove the .value from the call in $.getJSON to

```
       $.getJSON('http://localhost:56502/KnockoutJS/CascadingDropdown/Cities/' + 
                  country, null, function (response) {          // <<<<<<<<<<< removed .value
            viewModel.cities(response);
        });
```